# Error while update Ruby version from 2.6.10 to 3.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm encountering difficulties while attempting to update my Ruby version using RVM. I've followed the recommended steps, including updating RVM itself, installing the latest stable Ruby version, and setting it as the default. However, despite these efforts, the Ruby version in my environment does not seem to update successfully. When I run commands like ruby --version, it still shows the older version. I've also tried cleaning up RVM, restarting my shell, and double-checking my PATH, but the issue persists. Any guidance or insights on how to troubleshoot and successfully update my Ruby version using RVM would be greatly appreciated.

when i run rvm install 3.0.0 for exemple that's what i get

````
Error running '__rvm_make -j8', please read /Users/apple/.rvm/log/1703760048_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.```
````

and when i go to check the make log that's what i get:

```
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1837:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
    ancdata.c:1440:36: note: ')' token is here
            ary = rb_attr_get(ctl, rb_intern("unix_rights"));
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                       ^
    make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....`your text`
    linking shared-object json/ext/parser.bundle
    raddrinfo.c:2687:18: warning: '(' and '{' tokens introducing statement expression appear in         different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    id_timeout = rb_intern("timeout");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:23: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                      ^
raddrinfo.c:2687:18: note: '{' token is here
    id_timeout = rb_intern("timeout");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1832:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    {                                                   \
    ^
raddrinfo.c:2687:18: warning: '}' and ')' tokens terminating statement expression appear in different macro expansion contexts [-Wcompound-token-split-by-macro]
    id_timeout = rb_intern("timeout");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:24: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1837:5: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE'
    }
    ^
raddrinfo.c:2687:18: note: ')' token is here
    id_timeout = rb_intern("timeout");
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../.././include/ruby/ruby.h:1847:56: note: expanded from macro 'rb_intern'
        __extension__ (RUBY_CONST_ID_CACHE((ID), (str))) : \
                                                       ^
18 warnings generated.
30 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
linking shared-object socket.bundle
12 warnings generated.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

and when i try with rbenv i get this

```
BUILD FAILED (macOS 13.6.1 on x86_64 using ruby-build 20231225)
```

I followed the recommended steps for the update process. This included updating RVM itself using rvm get stable, installing the latest stable Ruby version with rvm install ruby --latest, and setting the newly installed version as the default with rvm use ruby --default.

Comment: Consider switching to asdf. I did years ago and it's a very smooth experience. Here's what upgrading looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77739605/how-can-i-upgrade-ruby-version-from-3-2-2-to-3-3-0-using-asdf/77743412#77743412

Answer (score 0):

Since your makefile has the error `make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2` I'm going to take a stab at this and say you need to link the appropriate Openssl binary. So in your terminal issue the command:

```
which openssl
```

and if you get something like:

```
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

then you need to tell `make` where your openssl binary is. Using the path returned from the `which` command try this:

```
rvm install ruby-3.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

substitute what ever your openssl path is.