# How can I upgrade Ruby version from 3.2.2 to 3.3.0 using asdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, asdf

I am currently using Ruby version 3.2.2 on Ubuntu 22.04, which I installed using asdf. I would like to upgrade to version 3.3.0.

When I run `asdf install ruby 3.3.0`, I keep getting the error message `ruby-build: definition not found: 3.3.0.`

Can anyone guide me on how to upgrade my Ruby version to 3.3.0 using asdf?

I have tried running `asdf install ruby 3.3.0` where I expected it to upgrade my version to Ruby 3.3.0.

Comment: Updating asdf plugin using the following command '
asdf plugin update ruby' has worked for me.
You should be able to install 3.3.0 afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Updating asdf plugin using the following command  `asdf plugin update ruby` has worked for me.
You should be able to install 3.3.0 afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it using devops to make my version predictable:

1. I update all the languages I use, because why not? You'll see which ones get a new version to install:

```bash
$ asdf plugin update --all
```

2. I look and see what versions of Ruby are available. And hey! Ruby 3.3.0 is there:

```bash
$ asdf list all ruby
```

3. Then, to keep things sane and devops, I edit the Ruby entry in whatever project I want to use it. Or, maybe I'll just make it the default for my user account:

```bash
$ vi ~/.tool-versions
```

This opens up my current defaults, which I edit to change the `ruby` line:

```
elixir 1.16.0-otp-26
erlang 26.1.2
gleam  0.33.0
python 3.12.1
ruby   3.3.0
```

4. For the last step, I install the new version the easy way. This looks at the nearest `.tool-versions` and installs them:

```bash
$ asdf install
```

You can verify you're running the new version like this:

```bash
$ ruby -v                                                                                   
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [arm64-darwin23]
```

**Finally**, this isn't required, but I always update the essentials when I install a new interpreter:

```bash
$ gem update --system ; gem update bundler
```

Comment: Great answer! Only thing I would add is that your project may have a .tool-version file in its root directory which will supersede the global .tool-version in your home directory; it needs to be updated too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using rvm and arch:
Just follow these steps:

1.First Uninstall existing Homebrew
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"

2.Then remove the homebrew folder

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

3.It will reinstall homebrew

```
arch -arm64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

4.Now install the ruby 3.3.0, It will install with all required binaries

```
arch -arm64 rvm install 3.3.0
```

5.Use this to see available ruby versions

```
rvm list
```

6.Then just run

```
rvm use 3.3.0
```

**NOTE**: These steps always worked for me to have different ruby versions and i can select the desired one easily